# How to play sound in button mouse over?

Tags: wpf

```
  <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Click Me!">
           <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                          < here i want to play sound but how?>
                         </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
         </Button.Style>
   </Button>
```

I try but not find any event to do this if anyone knows then please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily attach handlers to the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx) and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave) events:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Click Me!"
        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" /> 

private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // start playing
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // stop playing
}
```